# Excel CustomViews as a list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared spreadsheet which has been used for a number of years that has multiple CustomViews (Personal Views for multiple users) applied to it. I'd like to communicate to all of these users as a way to determine which are still in use, or if the users are still using the spreadsheets at all etc.

I'd therefore like to extract the data as list, which should match Outlook usernames and make life easier. All I can find is ways to use the list in a drop down ComboBox, which tells me it's accessible, but I've not got further than this. Happy for it to be a one-time thing, VBA is fine (and I assume necessary). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of views used in a workbook can be accessed using the property `CustomViews` of the workbook. However, the views doesn't provide much usefull information except the name, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.CustomView). So it neither tells which sheet will get the active sheet nor which rows/columns are visible or hidden.

You are probably out of look to figure out *who* created the view or if it is used at all. There is a property `Creator` for a view object, but that's misleading as it's only an information about which application created the view - it seems that this is needed when running on a Mac, and has always the value 1480803660 (hex 5843454C, or the string `XCEL`).

The following code will loop over all views of the current workbook and list infos to the immediate window - you can easily adapt this to write it to a sheet, a file or a custom data structure, whatever you need. I use the method `Show` to activate the view and figure out which sheet is displayed and which range (limited to the used range) is visible.

```
Sub ListViews()
    Dim v As CustomView
    For Each v In ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews
        v.Show
        With ActiveSheet
            Dim r As Range
            Set r = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            If r Is Nothing Then Set r = .Cells(1, 1)
            Debug.Print v.Name, .Name, r.Address
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought this had crashed Excel but it got there in the end! This is pretty much exactly what I need. All of the CustomViews is these workbooks are named 'First Name Surname - Personal View' so nothing fancy is needed to find out who created it. I just want to check if it needs to actually cycle through each of the views in order to get the information? I'm guessing yes, but I thought I'd at least ask.

Comment: You will need to cycle through all views but that's easy (see code). If you are not interested in the sheet/range that is displayed, you don't need to use `show` and the logic to get the range, instead, just use `v.Name`

Comment: Thanks - just another comment as I've just realised something re the sheet names and ranges that I didn't notice initially. If you have another workbook open, the sheet name and ranges for some users listed is showing a name and range for the active sheet of the other open workbook. As you mentioned though, I don't necessarily need this info although it is useful, if it works.

Comment: Replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` - if the code is in the workbook where you want to look at. If not, use something like `Application.Workbooks("yourWorkbookname")` to specify the workbook (note that it needs to be open).

Comment: Both of those options seem to yield the same result. The first 9 views listed are correct and then it goes off piste. I'm wondering if the those particular views are not in use and don't have that data? This is a very old spreadsheet! But to be fair, that's a bonus. Happy that the original answer solves my original problem.

Comment: I just closed all other workbooks and ran it and now the spreadsheet name part is blank for all customviews listed. CustomView names and ranges all fine and correct though. Just in case you were interested!